# Extend Powermail Finisher with Attachment

Tags: typo3, powermail

how can i add an attachment in my finisher ?  I have an comma separated list of files (without FAL)

- TYPO3 7.6
- Powermail 3.8.0

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in this direction, i hoped anyone can tell me, where i can find the addAttachment function. :-/ I have the completly Mail model with all information, i don´t know, how to add an attachment to user mail. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finisher is the wrong origin to add an attachment to a mail, because finishers (as the name already tells you) are called after everything else. 
To find a solution there are some ideas (using a signal like "sendTemplateEmailBeforeSend" or so). But the simplest way is to always create an XML file with a fix name on a fix location before the mails are sent and attach this to the mail (I think I read something that you want to add a dynamically XML-file to your mails).
That could be done with a dataProcessor - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddDataProcessors/Index.html for details.

Comment: of course... SignalSlot ... omg thank you... now its working... thank you alex